# why aren't images loading in preview?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, vite

I am using react.js and the problem that I am having is that the images wont load in npm run preview even though I included them in the public folder, reconfigured the image paths, and they are included in the assets folder in the dist folder. all of the images are showing on the local preview of the website

This is how it looks like

[image: project folders]

these are my paths for my images in the assets folder

```
export default [
  {
    title: "Flaco Ramirez Boxing Website",
    imgUrl: "/assets/frb.png",
    stack: ["Typescript", "React", "Tailwind", "Vite"],
    link: "",
  },
  {
    title: "Portfolio Website ",
    imgUrl: "/assets/portfolio.jpeg",
    stack: ["Javascript", "React", "Tailwind", "Vite"],
    link: "",
  },
  {
    title: "Discord Bot ",
    imgUrl: "/assets/discord.png",
    stack: ["Python", "Discord.py"],
    link: "",
  },
];
```

in PortfolioItem.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

export function PortfolioItem({ title, imgUrl, stack, link }) {
   return (
      <a 
         href={link}
         target="_blank"
         rel="noopener noreferrer"
         className="border-2 border-stone-900 dark:border-white rounded-md overflow-hidden"
      >
         <img
            src={imgUrl}
            alt="portfolio" 
            className="w-full h-36 md:h-48 object-cover cursor-pointer"
         />
         <div className="w-full p-4">
            <h3 className="text-lg md:text-xl dark:text-white mb-2 md:mb-3 font-semibold ">{title}</h3>
            <p className="flex flex-wrap gap-2 flex-row items-center justify-start text-xs md:text-sm dark:text-white ">
               {stack.map(item => (
                  <span className="inline-block px-2 py-1 font-semibold border-2 border-stone-900 dark:border-white rounded-md">
                     {item}
                  </span>
               ))}
            </p>
         </div>
      </a>
   )
}

export default PortfolioItem;
```

in Portfolio.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import porfolio from "../data/porfolio";
import PortfolioItem from "./PortfolioItem";

export function Portfolio() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-center">
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
        {porfolio.map((project) => (
          <PortfolioItem
            imgUrl={project.imgUrl}
            title={project.title}
            stack={project.stack}
            link={project.link}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Portfolio;
```

Comment: well... how are you attempting to display the images? you have an object here, but you need jsx that renders the image.

Comment: Is this using Vite or something else? Where does the `preview` script come from?

Comment: @Phil yes I am using vite

Comment: What do you see instead of the images? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to check the requests for the images and make sure the URLs are correct. What happens if you try and open one directly?

Comment: FYI `<PortfolioItem>` should have a `key` prop. Are you ignoring errors in your console?

Comment: @Phil it seems like it's trying to send a request to an old folder I had the images in before I put them in the assets folder, but I had the old folder deleted, any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Vite's `preview` task doesn't run a new build. It just serves the `dist` folder as-is.

If you want to always see the latest build via `preview`, I suggest you add a [*pre-script*](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts) in `package.json`...

```json
"scripts": {
   ...
 "prepreview": "npm run build", 
   "preview": "vite preview"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html). For dynamic images, it's best to do something like this...

```
/* create a util function or method or computed property
   also assuming your static images are in assets folder
*/
const getImageUrl = (path: string) => {
 return new URL(`../assets/${path}`, import.meta.url).href;
};

// and use in your code like this...
import React from 'react';

export function PortfolioItem({ title, imgUrl, stack, link }) {
 return (
  <a 
     href={link}
     target="_blank"
     rel="noopener noreferrer"
     className="border-2 border-stone-900 dark:border-white rounded-md 
      overflow-hidden"
  >
     <img
        src={getImageUrl(imgUrl)}
        alt="portfolio" 
        className="w-full h-36 md:h-48 object-cover cursor-pointer"
     />
     <div className="w-full p-4">
        <h3 className="text-lg md:text-xl dark:text-white mb-2 md:mb-3 
          font-semibold ">{title}</h3>
        <p className="flex flex-wrap gap-2 flex-row items-center 
          justify-start text-xs md:text-sm dark:text-white ">
           {stack.map(item => (
              <span className="inline-block px-2 py-1 font-semibold 
                border-2 border-stone-900 dark:border-white rounded-md">
                 {item}
              </span>
           ))}
        </p>
     </div>
  </a>
 )
}

export default PortfolioItem;
```

This works for me perfectly and I hope it helps someone.